# SQL select to return the highest state of a row based on a state order

Tags: sql

I have a table with a composite key of

(ID varchar(), named_state varchar()) + a datetime string column.

There are multiple consecutive name_state(s) that are added as rows
which follow a stateful insert order when an application event happens.
Example => "state1" => "state2" => "state3"
as they are added such as

```
insertion Row#1 ("1", "state1", "col3_time_value")
insertion Row#2 ("1", "state2", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#3 ("1", "state3", "col3_time_value")
```

I want to create a select query that returns one row
for each ID with the hightest state.

So if there are 5 rows in the database.

```
Insertion Row#1 ("1", "state1", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#2 ("1", "state2", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#3 ("1", "state3", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#4 ("2", "state1", "col3)_time_value")
Insertion Row#5 ("2", "state2", "col3_time_value")
```

It would return rows

```
Row#1 ("1", "state3", "col3_value")
Row#2 ("2", "state2", "col3_value").
```

How would I do that?

Also I have another query that in addition to above requirements
if a row has a specific such as state = "state3", it will return no rows for that ID.

So if there are 5 rows inserted in database

```
Insertion Row#1 ("1", "state1", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#1 ("1", "state2", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#3 ("1", "state3", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#4 ("2", "state1", "col3_time_value")
Insertion Row#5 ("2", "state2", "col3_time_value")
```

It will return 1 row only because state "state3" is excluded.
Row#1 (2, "state2", "col3_time_value")

because for ID = "1" it ends with state "state3".

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by state desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that "highest state" corresponds to the ordering based on `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Ties` is the best solution :

```
 Select Top (1) with ties *
 From t
 Order by Row_Number() over (partition by id order by state desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
select *
  from your_table t
 Where not exists 
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where tt.id = t.id and tt.state > t.state)
```